# Maximum temperature possible on earth

Tags: thermodynamics, earth, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science, convection

What is maximum temperature that can we have on earth on a single day?
Lets say an air mass is static over an area and there is no way for air mass to move, sun warming it up would increase temperature of this air mass, now if convection assume to be zero, and heat transfer by radiation only, than this air mass can reach to what temperature during a 24 hour cycle?

I assume that after a certain limit, radiation and convection would start working strongly to have equilibrium of surroundings.

According to thermodynamics principles how high temp in theory can go before equalization process restrict any further increase?

Highest I found  till now was $58^\circ~\rm C$ in Libya.

Comment: You mean environmental daytime temperatures for the current climate? That's probably a question for meteorology. If you make an insulated black box with a glass plate in front... that's kind of the right question for physics and it will be a lot higher than Libya. A black body radiator absorbing $1kW/m^2$ in solar power will heat up to roughly 365K (92 degrees C). I would guess that many surfaces can even get hotter because of reflection of solar radiation.

Comment: If we work at it, earth could go the way of Venus, with a surface temperature of about 465C (740K). Now that's climate change!

Comment: @hdhondt: Not even by burning all the carbon can we get to 90 bars of CO2 partial pressure. There is not enough oxygen for that.

Comment: @CuriousOne: now *I'm* the "curious one":  I'm convinced the Earth doesn't heat up like a black body because of constant circulation in our atmosphere (the meteorology part of this question).  But, I'm also curious, would *albedo* play a role in keeping the Earth's surface temperature lower than 365K?

Comment: @pr1268: Now you are getting into the really nasty climate stuff. hdhondt has a point, Venus has ultra-high albedo and ultra-high surface temperature. With an Earth-like atmosphere and without too much water it could actually be Earth-like. There is no simple answer to that question. One thing is certain, we will be a whole lot hotter for quite a while once the polar caps are gone.

Comment: @CuriousOne You're forgetting carbonate rocks. I don't imply it's likely to happen, even if we try a lot harder than we're doing now, but the CO2 is there.

Comment: It does belong to physics as fluid dynamics is inviolved

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1593

Comment: @hdhondt: I am well aware of those, but that won't happen while we are here or because of anything we do. For that transition to occur the entire water will have to go and the subduction will have to stop, won't it? Yes, that's the future one or two billion years from now, hardly something we have to worry about.

Comment: You really do need to clarify this question a bit. We could go by the globally, yearly average temperature (about 16C currently) or we could literally give you "the highest temperature possible on Earth" which so far has been in the millions of degrees for fusion research. "If half the Earth were magically turned into anti-matter and annihilated the other half instantly what would be the temperature?" As it stands the question allows such extravagant interpretations.