# Max. air temperature on Earth

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science, geophysics

Is there any max. temperature that air on Earth could reach, assuming that solar radiation is standard and the average temperature on Earth is 14.6 like today? I mean, is there any chance that the temperature on Earth would reach in some place 80 C today? And I don't mean surface temperature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global warming and air temperature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418475/)

Comment: It's not a duplicate!

Comment: It *is* a duplicate of the unanswered question: [*Maximum temperature possible on earth*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253032/6319).

Comment: It is indeed the same question, and we do really seek to avoid that.  Otherwise you'd have 10 copied of every question. That's why the site coders took the effort to give you a list of similar questions when you type one up, so you can check. That said, it does happen; sometimes the question doesn't have the same terms.  It isn't anything to be ashamed or that administrators want to penalize for if accidental... just good to try to look carefully each time. At least it happened that this case you got some useful answers. In the end the Q is very hypothetical, and I doubt there's a true answer.

Comment: Actually not sure it's entirely a duplicate in looking further?  The other question seems to delve into some unrealistic world assuming no convection.  This seems more straightforward to asking about the world as we know it know?

Comment: And patricoo, I gather you're asking about at official weather stations (at which thermometers are standardized at 2 meter above ground and there are quite a few other siting rules in place as well), yes? (Ironically, such temperatures could still be mistakenly called surface temperatures... since we do  often call such weather stations surface observation stations [to differentiate from scheduled upper air balloon soundings]... but you're right, true surface temperature are different than the official temperatures you hear/see reported, and would rely more upon what the ground is made of)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a clear temperature cut-off, no.  There are poorly-understood things called ['heat bursts'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_burst) which are *alleged* to have driven near-surface air temperatures to over $70^\circ\mathrm{C}$, but as far as I know nothing has actually been verified.  Heat bursts are believed to be due to a parcel of air falling rapidly and getting adiabatically heated on the way down, but, as I say, I don't think they are well understood.

Clearly such events are transient.

Note that as gerrit points out in a comment, *surface* temperatures can get significantly higher, with a good example being the famous 'hot tin roof'.

Comment: **Surface** temperature can easily reach over 70°C (“a hot tin roof”).  You probably mean near-surface air temperature (T at 2 metre).

Comment: @gerrit: good point.  Yes I do mean near-surface (which I thought was 1.5m but it looks as if it's officially 2m as you say).  I will amend my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. The part of the atmosphere we live in is called the Troposphere. This layer goes from the earth's surface to around 12 km or 7-8 miles altitude. This layer of the atmosphere is heated mostly by IR emission from the earth. This fact and the decrease in pressure causes a decrease in temperature as height increases. The next layer, the stratosphere, is the first part of the atmosphere that gets warmer as altitude increases.  This layer extends to around 50 km or 31 miles altitude. Much higher than humans ever go (except astronauts). While this layer gets warmer as altitude increases the temperature at the top of the troposphere may be as low as -60 degrees C so it only reaches maybe of the  0 degrees C at the top of the stratosphere. Other higher layers may gey much hotter but animal life doesn't exist there.

References: Wikipedia webpage on atmospherical Layers, and UCAR Center for Science Education webpage Layer of Earths Atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

No. The [highest recorded temperature](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/highest-recorded-temperature/) of the air was 56.7°C (134°F), which was measured on 10 July 1913 at Greenland Ranch, Death Valley, California, USA.